# Count Words and Extract numbers from string and sum them

Tags: c#, numbers

1) I need to count how much words i have in the sentence.

But what if i have more than one white space? It will count as a word. Need solution for this.

```
There is four words. / count as 4 words
There is four  words. / count as 5 words
```

I use:

```
 int countWords = txt.Split().Length;
```

2) I need to extract numbers from string and then get sum. My code is not working, No overload for method error.

All my code:

```
            Console.Write("Ievadiet tekstu: ");
            string txt = Console.ReadLine();
            int sum = 0;


            int countWords = txt.Split().Length;

            foreach (char num in txt)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(num))
                    sum += Int32.TryParse(num).ToString();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("There are {0} words in this sentence.",countWords);
            Console.WriteLine("Summ is "+sum);
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an example that does this exact thing - See Remarks

Comment: [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will help.

Comment: Do you want to sum the "words" which could be parsed to `int`? Then do that, use `int.TryParse` on all words which were extracted by `text.Split(new char[] {  }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Comment: So do you need to be able to convert words to numbers too? Like `There are four words`, does that need to be able to parse `four`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload of `String.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. You can use an empty `char[]`(or `string[]`) to get the same behaviour as [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) without an argument, so that it splits by all [white-space characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) like space,tab or new-line characters.

If you want to sum the "words" which could be parsed to `int` then do that, use `int.TryParse` on all words which were extracted by `String.Split`. You could use LINQ:

```
string[] words = text.Split(new char[] {}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int wordCount = words.Length;
int num = 0;
int sum = words.Where(w => int.TryParse(w, out num)).Sum(w => num);
```

Comment: Can you tell me, is there a possible way to rewrite this code? int wordCount = text.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
Is there a possible way to count words with FOR or FOREACH?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple console app to do what you intend to. 
It uses a Regular expression to capture number characters and sums them. The TryParse is just a fail-safe (i believe it is not needed in this case since the regex ensures only digits are captured).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex digitRegex = new Regex("(\\d)");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();

        int wordCount = text.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (Match x in digitRegex.Matches(text, 0))
        {
            int num;
            if (int.TryParse(x.Value, out num))
                sum += num;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Word Count:{0}, Digits Total:{1}", wordCount, sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: Can you tell me, is there a possible way to rewrite this code? int wordCount = text.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
Is there a possible way to count words with FOR or FOREACH?

Comment: There is allways a way to whatever you want to do.. But you have to ask yourself if you need that way. Currently you have out of the box solutions for your problem. Do you really want to try and go that way? Can you make a better solution than the one that's already provided? 
Given that consider if you really need to do so. If you want to just do it for fun then you could allways iterate every char in the string and do the required validations to each of them. But this isn't very cost-efficient.